# Python and named pipes, how to wait before re-open?

Tags: python, concurrency, named-pipes

I'm developing a two ways IPC using named pipes, but I've this concurrency problem :

writer.py:

```
with open("fifo", "w") as f:
   f.write("hello")
with open("fifo", "w") as f:
   f.write("hello2")
```

reader.py:

```
with open("fifo", "r") as f:
   f.read()
with open("fifo", "r") as f:
   f.read()
```

the problem is :

```
writer opens the fifo
reader opens the fifo
writer writes "hello"
writer closes the fifo
writer opens the fifo
writer writes "hello2"
reader reads "hellohello2"
writer closes the fifo
reader closes the fifo
reader opens the fifo
reader hangs up
```

Is there a way (without using a protocol to control) to synchronize and force writer to wait that reader has closed the fifo too before re-opening ?

Comment: The argument to `read` should be the number of characters to read, not a string. I don't even know how this works at all, let alone "incorrectly". For that matter, have you actually made a real named pipe using `os.mkfifo`, or are you just opening a random file named `fifo`?

Comment: sorry for the copy-paste fail about the `read()`. Actually I read to the EOF (-1 default argument to read with this meaning).
I am opening a real posix named-pipe, made by mkfifo (or `os.mkfifo()` in the python script)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way would be to use a terminating character writer side, and read one char at a time until the terminating character reader side.

So it could be something like:

writer.py:

```
with open("fifo", "w") as f:
   f.write("hello\n")
with open("fifo", "w") as f:
   f.write("hello2\n")
```

reader.py

```
def do_readline(f):
    line = ""
        while True:

        c = f.read(1)
        line += c
        if c == '\n':
            break
    return line

with open("fifo", "r") as f:
   do_readline(f)
with open("fifo", "r") as f:
   do_readline(f)
```

Comment: Well, using read_line() would be more efficient in this case, but I guess there is no solution for binary files of any size using all char-codes without using another fifo for making a control
thanks any way